# SQL: remove spaces from column

Tags: sql

I'd like to remove all spaces contained within the values of a specific column, but my knowledge on SQL is admittedly quite limited.
(I've done several searches in these forums but couldn't find a solution that worked for me).

My table is called wp_test

The column is called: image

values in the column typically look something like this: *books and brochures/my image.jpg*

all spaces need to be removed so it looks like this: *booksandbrochures/myimage.jpg*

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which SQL platform you are using, but below is for MySQL/SQL Server:

```
SELECT REPLACE(Image, ' ', '') as Image_Modified FROM wp_test;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Your time was appreciated, but in my case your solution didn't seem to do anything. 
FYI - I'm using phpMyAdmin with a typical wordpress site.

I've since found a solution that has worked, and will post that as my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution worked for me:

```
UPDATE wp_test
SET image = REPLACE(image, ' ', '');
```